# два QTcpSocket конкурируют за одну функцию, почему происходит параллельный вызов в одном потоке?

Tags: qt, многопоточность

Всем привет!

Есть класс в котором два QTcpSocket и один QTimer.

```
StateTimer = new QTimer(this);
ControlSock = new QTcpSocket(this);
StatSock = new QTcpSocket(this);
```

для них внутри класса определены 5 слотов и все они подключены вот так

```
QObject::connect(StateTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Timer_slot()));
QObject::connect(ControlSock, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),   this, SLOT(ControlSockStateChange_slot(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
QObject::connect(StatSock, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(StatSockStateChange_slot(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
QObject::connect(ControlSock, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(ControlSockError_slot(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
QObject::connect(StatSock, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(StatSockError_slot(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

во всех слотах вызывается одна и та же функция. В этой функции я  сделал

```
counter++;
qDebug() << "call: " << (int) QThread::currentThreadId();
qDebug() << "counter: " <<counter;
....
counter--;
return;
```

В моем идеальном мире что-бы не происходило с сетью и таймером функция должна всегда писать "counter: 1". Однако при разрыве соединения (физически вырвали кабель) когда рушатся 2 сокета разом, и генерят кроме 2 смен состояний еще и ошибки, происходит 6 вызовов функции. Но не последовательно как я предполагал, а параллельно!
я получаю запись

> call: 9600 
>   counter: 1
>
> call: 9600 
>   counter: 2
>
> call: 9600 
>   counter: 3
>
> call: 9600 
>   counter: 4
>
> call: 9600 
>   counter: 5

Объясните люди добрые какого же фига происходит? Как может происходит вызов функции из одного потока по событиям несколько раз? Внутри функции естественно никаких обработчиков очереди сообщений не дергаю.

И второй вопрос, если я делаю соединение сигнал - слот, соединение в авто режиме, а потом один из объектов переношу в другой трид, то оно из прямого на очередь смениться автоматически? Или за этим надо следить и соединять все уже после того как распихал объекты по тридам или сразу закладывать правильные типы соединения? 
Или же при авто соединении вид вызова определяется уже во время работы?

Comment: Единственное объяснение что я нашел происходящему такое: внутри вызываемой функции, той в которую заходит поток несколько раз вызываются методы ControlSock->state()  и ControlSock->disconnectFromHost();    Есть большое подозрения что внутри этих методов дергается обработка очереди сообщений с выбором и исполнением нового сообщения....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной такого поведения является то что в функции была работа с сокетами

```
if(ControlSock->state() != QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
  ControlSock->abort();
```

или

```
if(ControlSock->state() != QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
   ControlSock->disconnectFromHost();
```

внутри этих методов создавались еще сигналы, которые прямым вызовом опять проходили в ту же функцию. Поскольку функция одна на оба сокета то я ловил сигналы от обоих.